# Issues Setting Up PostgreSQL Read Replica Across Datacenters

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on setting up a read replica for PostgreSQL across two datacenters over the internet. As part of the setup, I've modified the `pg_hba.conf` file on the primary server (`server-a`) to include the following:

```
host    replication     replication_user     <server-b-ip>/32      trust
```

(Note: I'm aware that using `trust` is not recommended for production)

To verify the connection from the replica server (`server-b`), I ran a query against `server-a` using:

```bash
psql -h <server-a-ip> -U replication_user -d postgres -c "SELECT 1;"
```

This works, indicating that the basic connectivity and authentication are working as expected.

However, when I try to initiate a full backup on `server-b` using `pg_basebackup` to prepare the replica, I encounter an error:

```bash
pg_basebackup -h <server-a-ip> -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -U replication_user -v -P --wal-method=stream
```

The command returns the following error message:

```
pg_basebackup: error: connection to server at "<server-a-ip>", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "<server-b-ip>", user "replication_user", no encryption
```

Prior to these steps, I have created a replication role for the user `replication_user` with the necessary permissions:

```sql
CREATE ROLE replication_user REPLICATION LOGIN PASSWORD 'mypassword';
```

It seems I might be missing a step or need to adjust my configuration. Does anyone have insights on what else needs to be done to successfully establish the read replica?